# Is multiplying by a measurable function $V$ always self-adjoint?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, quantum-mechanics

There are a handful of results establishing conditions on the measurable real-valued function $V(x)$ under which the operator:

$$-\Delta + V(x)$$

Is (essentially) self-adjoint on $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$. My question is: Is the operator $V(x)$ by itself always self-adjoint? My instinct is no: Something sufficiently ugly like:

$$V(x) = \frac{1}{\sin(1/x)}$$

With infinitely many singularities near the origin ought to do it. And, if it is not true that multiplication by all measurable functions is self-adjoint, is there a relatively simple necessary and sufficient condition? Being integrable on every compact set seems sufficient but perhaps too strong.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that multiplication by $V$ will be self-adjoint if $V\in L^2_\text{loc}$.

**EDIT:** This source seems to corroborate: http://books.google.com/books?id=9IB00lNjxUMC&pg=PA125&lpg=PA125&dq=multiplication+by+integrable+function+self-adjoint&source=bl&ots=IkvqXeuKeo&sig=YiRdXtuvJFmcP6wNgmyXltYbB_w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Yd8lUf-QKIWn0AGEwYGoCQ&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=multiplication%20by%20integrable%20function%20self-adjoint&f=false

Comment: It says "In conclusion, we note that the condition of local square-integrability can be weakened to the condition that V(x) be finite almost everywhere and measurable".. that seems like basically not a restriction at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Weidmann: Linear Operators in Hilbert spaces](http://books.google.hu/books/about/Linear_operators_in_Hilbert_spaces.html?id=_SDvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Example 1. (page 51) is where the multiplication operator is defined.
Example 2 on page 91 shows that for an arbitrary measurable $V$ you always get a (densely defined) selfadjoint (but not necessarily bounded) operator. If you want it a bounded operator, you need it essentially bounded.

Summarizing, there is no restriction at all.